# What is the replacement for Angular @angular/http URLSearchParams class in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am currently using the @angular/http URLSearchParams class to retrieve URL params. In Angular 5 it is noted that this is deprecated but I do not see an appropriate class that replaces URLSearchParams in the way I am currently using it.

```
constructor() { 
    this.urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.substring(1));
    this.custno = this.urlSearchParams.get('custno');
    this.plan = this.urlSearchParams.get('plan');
}
```

Note: I am not using and appRoutingModule since it is overkill for the SPA I am creating.

What would be the correct solution for replacing the @angular/common/http URLSearchParams class in this context?

Comment: Take a look at the `URLSearchParams` docs, they specificy that you should use `@angular/common/http` instead: https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams

Comment: The docs are not very helpful in this instance. They mention use `@angular/common/http`, but nothing about which specific class is meant to replace `URLSearchParams`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The replacement is `HttpParams`.

```
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
```

[Official docs from angular.](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams)

Comment: Ahh... yes I see this could work. I'm going to implement this and see how it goes. I see I referenced the wrong package in my post it should have been @angular/http

Comment: Thanks for the direction. The below does as I need: `constructor() { 
    this.httpParams = new HttpParams( { fromString: window.location.search.substring(1) } );    
    this.custno = this.httpParams.get('custno');  
    this.plan = this.httpParams.get('plan');  
  }`