# How to capture queryParams on page load in Angular 10?

Tags: angular, angular-router

In our application we set a recover proccess for user via ***?token=[TOKEN]*** query param.
Link to set new password is pointing to project's home page, like this:

```
https://our-project.com?token=[TOKEN]
```

During application loading proccess there is a RedirectRoleGuardService, that simply checks if user is
authentificated and if so redirects user to specific route. Here is the code:

```js
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.store.pipe(
      select(fromAuth.selectRole),
      tap((role) => {
        if (role)
          this.router.navigate([state.url + '-' + role], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' }).then()
        else
          this.router.navigate(['/main-unauth'], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' })
            .then()
      }),
      take(1),
      map(() => true)
    )
  }
```

As you can see, i tried using queryParamsHandling but it gave zero effect. QueryParams are not saved at all.

**Desired behaviour:**
I want to be able to capture queryParams during page load. URL: [https://our-project.com?token=[TOKEN]](https://our-project.com?token=%5BTOKEN%5D), i want to capture ?token with value and pass it along to url that is redirected by RedirectRoleGuardService

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using Angular 7 and am not sure if I understand exactly what you are asking for, but let's give it a go. If I am not that wrong, please try the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const queryStr = window.location.search;
    if (queryStr) {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryStr);
        const tokenFromUrl = urlParams.get('token');
        console.log("tokenFromUrl", tokenFromUrl);
        if (tokenFromUrl) {
            //do something
        }
        else {
            //redirect to Homepage
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated**: After some research, I found out that it is deprecated and according to [What is the replacement for Angular @angular/http URLSearchParams class in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559051/what-is-the-replacement-for-angular-angular-http-urlsearchparams-class-in-angul) you should probably use [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) to get `token`'s value.

Comment: Thank you for answer. That is a working way to pass token param. I thought may be my app would require to pass all queryParams, not just a token. How would you do this ? I am very sad that queryParamsHandling: 'preserve' is not working in canActivate guard. That would be simply perfect and clear solution. Looking at location.search queryparams are available, why then queryParamsHandling not working ?

Comment: You're welcome. If you know all the params, why not doing the same? For instance, if the  url is `https://our-project.com?token=[TOKEN]&param1=[PARAM1]&param2=[PARAM2]`, try to get them like `urlParams.get('token')`, `urlParams.get('param1')`, `urlParams.get('param2')`, etc. I am sorry I cannot help you with the `queryParamsHandling` and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

// You can use this in app component's ngOnInit function to get the queryParams

```
    const url = window.location.href;
    if (url.includes('?')) {
       const httpParams = new HttpParams({ fromString: url.split('?')[1] });
       const token = httpParams.get("token");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method in `ngOnInit`

```
// URL: localhost:4200/list?module=cars

this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        //params is an object
        const ParamLabels = Object.keys(params);

        // validate the queryParams otherwise redirect to dashboard

        if (!ParamLabels.includes('module')) this._router.navigate(['../dashboard']) 
        if (params['module'] == undefined) this._router.navigate(['../dashboard'])
        if (params['module'] == '') this._router.navigate(['../dashboard'])

        // some fn here
})
```